# mocking/spying private member of super class

Tags: mockito, stub, spy

I am writing junit test to test `BaseClass` method. The method uses super class members.
The `BaseClass` constructor invokes `super(arg1, arg2)`.
In the super(arg1, arg2) constructor there is a dependency injector setting a private member
of the super class.
When I am running the test, since the dependency is not set, the super() is throwing an
exception. I want to mock only that statement in the super() which is setting the private member with dependency injection. How to do with mockito ?

Answer (score 2):

Field injection is always a problem for testing. So whenever you have the choice, choose constructor injection instead.

You could start the dependency injector and make it inject a mock instead of a real class. Solutions would depend on the DI framework that you use actually (guice, cdi, ...) For guice you could use jukito, for cdi Arquillian for example. But it slows down the test execution and adds complexity to your test class.

As a alternative you could reflect the private field on an instance of you test class an simply set a mock. Something like:

```
instance = new TestObject();
Field injected = TestObject.class.getDeclaredField("injected");
injected.setAccessible(true);
injected.set(instance, mock(InjectedType.class));
```

while `TestObject` is the class that you want to test, `injected` the private field where something is injected an `InjectedType` the type of that private field.

Comment: thanks @Andreas_D,  but the problem is that the private member of super class is getting set in its constructor. So my code is throwing exception here itself : `instance = new TestObject();`